# Create a table based on value in a cell

Tags: excel

I have three columns in a sheet i.e Name, Salary and Income Tax.
And some people do not pay any Income Tax.

I want a table to be created automatically on another sheet with name and amount of income tax paid by each person and not display people who do not pay any income tax.

[image]

Comment: You could simply filter the Income Tax column for values >0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cell E3, enter this as an array formula (use <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>):
`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$3:A$8,SMALL(IF(C$3:C$8>0,ROW(A$3:A$8)-ROW(A$3)+1),ROWS(A$3:A3))),"")`

and drag down.

In F3, you have a choice of either:
`=IFERROR(INDEX(C$3:C$8,SMALL(IF(C$3:C$8>0,ROW(A$3:A$8)-ROW(A$3)+1),ROWS(A$3:A3))),"")`
(also as Array)
or 
`=INDEX($C$3:$C$8,MATCH(E3,$A$3:$A$8,0))`

Then, you can play around with the Income Tax amount in column C, and you'll see names show up or disappear, based on their Tax amount.  You can easily change the formula to show only those paying over $X amount in Income tax by changing the `0` to X in the E3 formula part `...If(C$3:C$8>X,Row(...`.

Comment: @pnuts - Just adjust the ranges, no?  Or am I missing something?